# Beautiful soup, XML to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, nlp

i am a beginer at machine learning and exploring with database for my nlp project. here i got the data from [http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdredze/datasets/sentiment/index2.html](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emdredze/datasets/sentiment/index2.html). and I am trying to create a pd dataframe where i want to parse the xml data , I also want to add a label(1) to the positive reviews, Can someone please help me with the code, a sample output has been given,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
positive_reviews = BeautifulSoup(open('/content/drive/MyDrive/sorted_data_acl/electronics/positive.review', encoding='utf-8').read())
positive_reviews = positive_reviews.findAll('review_text')
positive_reviews[0]



<review_text>
I purchased this unit due to frequent blackouts in my area and 2 power supplies going bad.  It will run my cable modem, router, PC, and LCD monitor for 5 minutes.  This is more than enough time to save work and shut down.   Equally important, I know that my electronics are receiving clean power.

I feel that this investment is minor compared to the loss of valuable data or the failure of equipment due to a power spike or an irregular power supply.

As always, Amazon had it to me in &lt;2 business days
</review_text>
```

Answer (score 1):

- the main issue is the note it is *pseudo xml*
- download **tar.gz** file and unzip / untar
- build dictionary of all files
- workaround to deal with *pseudo xml* - insert document element in string representation of document
- then simple case of using **list/dict comprehensions** to generate **pandas** constructor format
- **dfs** îs a dictionary of data frames ready to be used

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from tarfile import TarFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import io
import pandas as pd

# download tar with psuedo XML...
url = "http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emdredze/datasets/sentiment/domain_sentiment_data.tar.gz"
fn = Path.cwd().joinpath(url.split("/")[-1])
if not fn.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.raw.stream(1024, decode_content=False):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

# untar downloaded file and generate a dictionary of all files
TarFile.open(fn, "r:gz").extractall()
files = {f"{p.parent.name}/{p.name}":p for p in Path.cwd().joinpath("sorted_data_acl").glob("**/*") if p.is_file()}

# convert all files into dataframes in a dict
dfs = {}
for file in files.keys():
    with open(files[file]) as f: text = f.read()
    # psuedo xml where there is not root element stops it from being well formed
    # force it in...
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f"<root>{text}</root>", "xml")
    # simple case of each review is a row and each child element is a column
    dfs[file] = pd.DataFrame([{c.name:c.text.strip("\n") for c in r.children if c.name} for r in soup.find_all("review")])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Even though the code is a bit complicated for me :D. As i am not yet familiar with the pathlib module. but thanks a ton for your time. :)

Comment: the key part of the solution is inserting the document element to make the xml well-formed.  use of pathlib is just make the computer do the work of managing the files :-)